# my Django form is not validating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am having trouble validating my django form. my form is not validating. can anyone please examine my code and point out exactly where i am doing wrong. here are my codes.

models.py-

```
from django.db import models  
classcommentbox 
(models.Model) :             
      box=models.CharField(max_length=
      50 )
```

forms.py-

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . models import commentbox

class commentboxForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
              model=commentbox
              fields=['box']
```

views.py-

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import commentbox
from . forms import commentboxForm

def submit(request):
       if request.method=="POST":
           form=commentboxForm(request.
                     POST)
          if form.is_valid():
               return HttpResponse('valid')
          else:
               return HttpResponse('not 
               Valid')
       else:
             return HttpResponse("error")
```

template-

```
<form action="{% url 'poll:submit'   
%}"method="POST">
{%csrf_token%}
<label for"comment"> say something:   
</label>
<textarea class="form-control"   
rows="3" id="comment"> </textarea>
<button type="button"> submit
</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

add name attribute in textarea tag

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="box" rows="3" id="comment"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add name for the input,

In your template,

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="box" id="comment"> </textarea>
```

Or,

```
<input type="text" name="box" class="form-control">
```